# Scripting Rendered layers and Rendering

Tags: scripting

I have a list of 30+ objects in my blend file.  I want to render an animation with each object individually.  Currently, I rendering on all objects but one, hit render, disable rendering, change to the next object, repeat.  Is there a way I can script this and generate my rendered output for each object without changing manually?

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Taken from https://robertshenton.co.za/blog/blender-render-script/

```py
import bpy
import os

list = bpy.data.collections['collection_name'].objects
#list = bpy.context.selected_objects // uncomment this line if you want to target your selection instead

dest = "/path/to/folder/"
# some render settings
bpy.data.scenes[0].render.resolution_x = 1280
bpy.data.scenes[0].render.resolution_y = 720
bpy.context.scene.render.film_transparent = True
bpy.context.scene.render.image_settings.color_mode = 'RGBA'

# hide everything
for obj in list:
    obj.hide_render = True

# unhide and render one at a time
for obj in list:
    obj.hide_render = False
    bpy.data.scenes[0].render.filepath = os.path.join(dest, obj.name + '.png')
    bpy.ops.render.render(write_still=True)
    obj.hide_render = True
```

This works for one frame, you would have to edit it for rendering multiple frmes.